# Python3.7 - module not found even though it is listed in sys.path

Tags: python, package

I try to import some custom modules/packages but get the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'reader'".

I made sure that the absolute path to my custom package directory is listed in sys.path:

```
>>> os.getcwd()
'C:\\Python Projects\\reader'
>>> sys.path.append('C:\\Python Projects\\reader')
>>>
>>> sys.path
['', 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\python37.zip', 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37', 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Python Projects\\reader']
>>>
>>> import reader
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'reader'
```

Also, all the paths listed in sys.path (except for '' and C:\Python Projects\reader) have been added in Environment variables > System variables (I am using Win10).

Is there something else I should to in order to successfully import custom packages in my projects?

Thank you

Comment: `reader` is only a module if `reader/__init__.py` exists, in which case `C:\\Python Projects` is the directory to add the path. Otherwise, `reader` is simply a directory in which to *look* for modules, not a module itself.

Comment: If you are willing to test your project real-time during development, you may need to add the parent dir to PATH, not `reader` directly.
You could also create a package, build a wheel and install to your python. (see [pypa](https://www.pypa.io/en/latest/) or [this doc](https://the-hitchhikers-guide-to-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sys.path.append('C:\\Python Projects')
```

Then `import reader` will look for `reader` under `'C:\Python Projects'`, i.e. it will test for `'C:\Python Projects\reader'`. Currently it's testing for `'C:\Python Projects\reader\reader'`.